# I am making an android application to create routes with OSMDROID and the web router.project-osrm.org can not process the request (HTTP ERROR 503)

Tags: osmdroid, osrm

I am making an android application to create routes with OSMDROID and the web router.project-osrm.org can not process the request (HTTP ERROR 503).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj5Mo.png)

Comment: I am using the OSMRoadManager

Answer (score 1):

HTTP response off the server contains status message:

```
503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity
```

So problem is not on your side. The server has some limitations and cannot handle your request or it is maybe not working at all. I am not familiar with the project, but you may try to ask on their mailing list or IRC.

Answer (score 0):

The router.project-osrm.org is often down so you should just make your own server. It is really easy with the docker file.